# CSS major/minor overlapping problem using hover command

Tags: css

I have a small camera store/website (jdsrde.com)
Currently updating and wanted to add a zoom effect so when you scroll(hover) over images the get zoomed view without clicking to product page. 
Like a thumbnail, I have like 50 images.

The code works but for some reason the "zoom" image always goes behind the other images in the page. I wanted to see what I can do to fix this so that the "zoom" image goes to the front of the page layers. 
I have changed the z-index so many times but to no avail
I feel so stupid as i have been trying to figure this out for hours now to no avail and I know the answer is so easy.

I dont want to use java i prefer css.

here is the codes im using. Any help would be gladly appreciated!!!

CSS>>>>

```
#zoom { position: relative; top: 10px; left: 10px; width: 75px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); }
#zoom a.p1, #zoom a.p1:visited { border: 0pt none ; background: rgb(255, 255, 255) none repeat scroll 0%; display: block; width: 75px; height: 75px; text-decoration: none; top: 0pt; left: 0pt; }
#zoom a img { border: 0pt none ; }
#zoom a.p1:hover { text-decoration: none; background-color: rgb(140, 151, 163); color: rgb(0, 0, 0); }
#zoom a .large { border: 0px none ; display: block; position: fixed; width: 1px; height: 1px; top: -1px; left: -1px; }
#zoom a.p1:hover .large { border: 1px solid black; display: block; position: fixed; top: 0px; left: 250px; width: 300px; height: 200px; }
```

xhtml(of one of the images "zoom")>>>>>>

```
<div id="zoom" style="height: 106px; width: 150px;  height: 106px; left: 1400px; position: absolute; top: 325px; width: 150px; z-index: 1; " class="tinyText">
    <div style="position: relative; width: 150px; ">
        <a class="p1" href="Camera_Sears_35_RF.html" title="Camera_Sears_35_RF.html">
            <img src="All2020_files/shapez" alt="" style="height: 106px; left: 0px; position: absolute; top: 0px; width: 150px; " />
            <img class="large" src="All2020_files/z" title="Enlarged view of image" alt="Enlarged view of image" />
        </a>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Thanks again!!

Comment: How to format: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Just intend code lines by four spaces. It is even written right next to the textbox when you create a new question: *► indent code by 4 spaces*.

Answer (score 1):

z-index only affects other positioned elements in the same 'stacking context'. Since the div inside #zoom is also positioned relative the z-index on the anchor has no effect.

Try applying the z-index the the div, not the anchor. So adding the following should help:

```
#zoom>div:hover {
  z-index: 9;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. I had figured that but I couldnt get it to work. Sorry to ask this but I have tried so many ways to get this. 
Could you write it a bit more layman? I usually could understand but the simplicity has gotten my mind screwy. Im going to play around with this tho. Thank you again!!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. What don't you understand, and more imporantly did the given css solve the problem. Or don't you understand where to put it.